# Is there a way to bind and call at the same time?

Tags: javascript

Say I have code like this:

```
var boundFilter = this.filterCouriers.bind(this);
boundFilter();
```

**Is there a way to call that in one line?**

(Basically I am wondering if there is a way to call the bound method without having to store it in a variable.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use call

```
this.filterCouriers.call(this);
```

> The call() method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually. <sup>[MDN - call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)</sup>

Comment: Is there a difference between the `.call(this)` and `.bind(this)()`?  (I like the call syntax better.)

Comment: @Vaccano - The difference would be storing it in the variable for later use really. There is no difference from an end result point of view - they will both end up with the same result.

Answer (score 4):

`bind` returns a function, so you can call it immediatelly:

```
this.filterCouriers.bind(this)();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.filterCouriers.bind(this)();
```

This should do the trick. If not try this:

```
(this.filterCouriers.bind(this))();
```